# Unable to find the chromedriver executable... seems like it's in my path?

Tags: selenium, watir, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit with Watir and Ruby.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Gives an error: "Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from"...

I've downloaded and extracted the file (I've tried both 64 bit and 32 bit) into /usr/bin/ but I still get the error.

```
/usr/bin$ la | grep chrome
chromedriver
google-chrome
```

Here is my $PATH:

```
/usr/bin$ $PATH
bash:    /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/dan/.rvm/bin: No such file or directory
```

It looks ok to me, what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have recently updated instructions on [how to drive Chrome on Ubuntu](https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/manuscript/installation/ubuntu.md#chrome). Please check the instructions and feel free to ask here if you still have problems.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what I was missing but I followed the instructions again and it works.